# Are 'heavy' aggregate functions in RavenDB advisable?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, nosql, ravendb

I'm working on a proof-of-concept timesheet application in C# that allows users to simply enter lots of timesheet records. The proof-of-concept will use RavenDB as storage provider, however the question below is perhaps more related to the nosql concept in general.

A user will typically enter between 1 and about 10 records each working day. Let's just say that for the sake of the discussion there will be a lot of records by the end of the year (tens or hundreds of thousands) for this specific collection.

The model for a record will be defined as:

```cs
class TimesheetRecord {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTill { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Logically, the application will allow the users, or project managers, to create reports on the fly. Think of on the fly reports like:

- Total time spent for a project, customer or user
- Time spent for a project, or customer in a certain time span like a week, month or between certain dates
- Total amount of hours not approved already, by user - or for all users
- Etc.

Of course, it is an option to add additional fields, like integers for weeknumber, month etc. to decrease the amount of crunching needed to filter on date/period. The idea is to basically use `Query<T>` functions by preference in order to generate the desired data.

In a 'regular' relational table this all would be no problem. With or without normalization this woulb be a breeze. The proof-of-concept is based on: will it blend as well in a nosql variant? This question is because I'm having some doubts after being warned about these 'heavy' aggregate functions (like nested WHERE constraints and SUM etc.) not being ideal in a document store variant.

Considering all this, I have two questions:

1. Is this advisable in a nosql variant, specifically RavenDB?
2. Is the approach correct?

I can imagine storing all the data redundantly, instead of querying on the fly, would be more performant. Like in adding hours spent by a certain user in a Project() or Customer() object. This, however, will increase complexity with updates considerably. Not to mention create immense redundant data all over the collections, which on its turn seems like a direct violation of seperation of concern and DRY.

Any advise or thoughts would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of RavenDB, but it is not a silver bullet or golden hammer. It has scenarios for which it is *not* the best tool for the job, and this is probably one of them.

Specifically, document databases in general, and RavenDB in particular, aren't very applicable when the specific data access patterns are not known. RavenDB has the ability to create Map/Reduce indexes that can do some amazing things with aggregating data, but you have to know ahead of time how you want to aggregate it.

If you only have need for (let's say) 4 specific views on that data, then you can store that data in Raven, apply Map/Reduce indexes, and you will be able to access those reports with blazing speed because they will be asynchronously updated and always available with great performance, because the data will already be there and nothing has to be crunched at runtime. Of course, then some manager will go "You know what would be really great is if we could also see ***_*_**." If it's OK that manager's request will require additional development time to create a new Map/Reduce index, UI, etc., then Raven could still be the tool for the job.

However, it sounds like you have a scenario with a table of data that would essentially fit perfectly in Excel, and you want to be able to query that data in crazy ways that cannot be known until run time. In that case, you are better off going with a relational database. They were created specifically for that task and they're great at it.

Comment: Thanks, David. So, summarized you're stating that it's ok to use Raven for a limited set of predictable queries/aggregates (using map/reduce) and for others - go seek relational variants?

Comment: The big thing is for the aggregations. Those are what must be defined ahead of time. For normal Find By X, or Y, or Z, or whatever queries, Raven is pretty good about creating dynamic indexes on the fly to query data every which way and return that data, as long as you can put up with the auto index potentially being stale the first time you try to use it. Raven will even intelligently throw away auto-indexes that fall into disuse. You just simply can't have an auto Map/Reduce aggregation index.